# Use If in C# linq Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I want my method check if the Checkbox called "onlyPresence" checked then add a new where clause or new expression in where or use if in where.. but i get error on where I Use ** the line

```
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeInfo> GetAllVisibleEmployeesInfo(string sortBy, string name ,int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, string Department, bool onlyPresence )
    {
        name = Common.Converter.ConvertToFarsiYK(name ?? "").Trim();
        var GetNowString = Common.Date.GregorianToPersian(DateTime.Now.Date, Common.Date.DateStringType.Short);
        if (Department == null){Department = "";}

        using (LinqDataContext context = DataContext)
        {
            List<EmployeeInfo> result = context.vwDailyWorks
                .Where(q => (q.Visible == true))
                .Where(q => (q.DepartmentName.Contains(Department)))
                .Where(q => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ||
                                (q.FirstName.Contains(name) ||
                                q.LastName.Contains(name) ||
                                q.Position.Contains(name) ||
                                q.Floor.Contains(name) ||
                                (q.Ext_Tel ?? -1).ToString().Contains(name) ||
                                q.Email.Contains(name) ||
                                q.DepartmentName.Contains(name)))
                        )
                **.Where(w => { if (onlyPresence) { w.Even_Odd == 1}  } )**
                .GroupBy(t => t.EmployeeID)
                .Select(t => new EmployeeInfo
                {
                    FirstName = t.Max(s => s.FirstName),
                    LastName = t.Max(s => s.LastName),
                    Position = t.Max(s => s.Position),
                    DepartmentName = t.Max(s => s.DepartmentName),
                    Status2= GetPresent_Status(t.Key),
                    Extension = t.Max(s => s.Ext_Tel),
                    Info = GetPresenceInfo(t.Key, false),
                    ID = t.Key,
                    Email = t.Max(s => s.Email),
                    StatusInfo = GetStatusInfo(t.Key, false)
                }
                        )
                
                .OrderBy(sortBy)
                .Skip(startRowIndex)
                .Take(maximumRows)
                .ToList();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error that ur getting?

Comment: @HassanMonjezi That is not the same logic

Comment: @DavidG, I figured out the question logic is that `if (onlyPresence) { w.Even_Odd == 1}` which says `if(onlyPresence==true)` then check for `w.Even_Odd == 1`. but anyway regarding the logic, the problem  is that @Amirhosein Araghi is not returning the result outside of its if  statement.

Comment: @HassanMonjezi I'm just saying your logic is wrong, it should end with `true`.

Comment: @DavidG You are right.

Comment: It should be: `Where(w => onlyPresence? w.Even_Odd == 1 : true)`

Comment: @HassanMonjezi thank you it work seperately but I get nothing when another item (0) checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
.Where(w => !onlyPresence || w.Even_Odd == 1)
```

Comment: thank you but i dont know why when the another checkbox checked i got nothing

Comment: That is a new question, you have your answer!

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
using (LinqDataContext context = DataContext)
{
    List<EmployeeInfo> result = context.vwDailyWorks
        .Where(q => (q.Visible == true))
        .Where(q => (q.DepartmentName.Contains(Department)))
        .Where(q => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ||
                        (q.FirstName.Contains(name) ||
                        q.LastName.Contains(name) ||
                        q.Position.Contains(name) ||
                        q.Floor.Contains(name) ||
                        (q.Ext_Tel ?? -1).ToString().Contains(name) ||
                        q.Email.Contains(name) ||
                        q.DepartmentName.Contains(name)))
                );
                
    if (onlyPresence) 
    {
        result = result.Where(w =>  w.Even_Odd == 1 )
    }

     result = result
    .GroupBy(t => t.EmployeeID)
    .Select(t => new EmployeeInfo
    {
        FirstName = t.Max(s => s.FirstName),
        LastName = t.Max(s => s.LastName),
        Position = t.Max(s => s.Position),
        DepartmentName = t.Max(s => s.DepartmentName),
        Status2= GetPresent_Status(t.Key),
        Extension = t.Max(s => s.Ext_Tel),
        Info = GetPresenceInfo(t.Key, false),
        ID = t.Key,
        Email = t.Max(s => s.Email),
        StatusInfo = GetStatusInfo(t.Key, false)
    })
    .OrderBy(sortBy)
    .Skip(startRowIndex)
    .Take(maximumRows)
    .ToList();
    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, parameter `predicate` in [Queryable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where) should be an `Expression<Func<VwDailyWork,bool>>`. Or in normal language: a method that takes a VwDailyWork object and returns a bool

```
w => { if (onlyPresence) { w.Even_Odd == 1}
```

is not a `Func<VwDailyWork,bool>`. What would you want if `!onlyPresence`? Not check at all?

```
w => !onlyPresence) || (w.Even_Odd == 1)
```

This is the same af:
if (onlyPresence)
return w.Even_odd == 1;
else
return true;

### There is room for improvement

If you do it like you suggested, then the value of onlyPresence will be calculated once per evaluated VwDailyWork. Similary you check the emptyness of name several times. Wouldn't it be better to evaluate them only once?

```
IQueryable<VwDailyWorks> query = dbContext.vwDailyWorks
    .Where(q => q.Visible && q.DepartmentName.Contains(Department);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    // add the name checks
    query = query.Where(q => q.FirstName.Contains(name) || ...);
}

if (onlyPresence)
{
    // add the check for even_odd == 1
    query = query.Where(q => q.even_odd == 1);
}
```

Now you are certain the name and onlyPresence are checked only once.

If you do this more often, my advice would be to create an extension method for this. If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IQueryable<VwDailyWorks> QueryVwDailyWorks(
    this LinqDataContext dbContext
    string name,
    string department,
    bool onlyPresence)
{
    IQueryable<VwDailyWorks> query = dbContext.vwDailyWorks
        .Where(q => q.Visible
                 && q.DepartmentName.Contains(Department);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            // add the name checks
            query = query.Where(q => q.FirstName.Contains(name) || ...);
        }

        if (onlyPresence)
        {
            // add the check for even_odd == 1
            query = query.Where(q => q.even_odd == 1);
        }

    }
    return query;
}
```

Usage:

```
string name = ...
string department = ...
bool onlyPresence = ...

using (var dbContext  = new DataContext())
{

     var result = dbContext.QueryVwDailyWorks(name, department, onlyPresence)

         // continue with your original query
         .GroupBy(t => t.EmployeeId)
         .Select(...)
         .OrderBy(...)
         .Skip(...)
         .Take(...)
         .ToList();
```